# How do I use swift generic Decodable protocol in generic functions

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I would like to write a generic function which parses the result and return in success block of closure or sends back error in failure block.

I'm getting error like this **'Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred'**.

Here is my sample code.

```
let jsonString = """
{
"id": 1,
"msg": "Sample msg"
}
"""

struct Post: Codable {
    var id: String?
    var msg: String?
}

enum PostError: Error {
    case empty
}


func fetch<T:Decodable>(_ completion: @escaping (Result<T?, PostError>) -> Void)  {

        do {
            let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)
            let post = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
            completion(.success(post))
        }
        catch {
            completion(.failure(.empty))
        }
    }


fetch { res in
        switch res {
        case .success( let p):
            print(p.description)

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Here is the error I'm getting.

[image: I'm getting error like this.]

Comment: I'm guessing you expect `res` to be a `Result<Post?, PostError>`? But `Post?` doesn't have a `description` property though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accept the generic type as a parameter, like so:

```
func fetchObject<T:Decodable>(ofType type: T.Type, _ completion: @escaping (Result<T, PostError>) -> Void)  {
   do {
      let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)
      let post = try JSONDecoder().decode(type, from: data)
      completion(.success(post))
   }
   catch {
      completion(.failure(.empty))
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
fetchObject(ofType: Post.self) { res in
   switch res {
       case .success(let post):
          print(post.description)
       case .failure(let error):
          print(error)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you're trying to do, but the main problem is that you never specify the type. The compiler knows you want to call `fetch` but it doesn't know what you want to fetch or what to parse it to.

If you take a look at your `fetch` call there is nowhere there where the compiler could possibly tell what you're trying to do or what you expect to happen.

You either have to:

#### 1. Pass the type as a parameter

```swift
func fetch<T: Decodable>(_ type: T.Type, _ completion: @escaping (Result<T, PostError>) -> Void)  {

    do {
        let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)
        let post = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
        completion(.success(post))
    }
    catch {
        completion(.failure(.empty))
    }
}


fetch(Post.self) { res in
        switch res {
        case .success(let p):
            print(p)

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

or...

#### 2. Specify the type at instantiation of the object that the function is a member of:

```swift
struct Fetcher<T: Decodable> {

    func fetch(_ completion: @escaping (Result<T, PostError>) -> Void)  {

        do {
            let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)
            let post = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
            completion(.success(post))
        }
        catch {
            completion(.failure(.empty))
        }
    }
}

let fetcher = Fetcher<Post>()
fetcher.fetch { res in
    switch res {
    case .success(let p):
        print(p)

    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```